# P-value vs. F-statistics. What is really the difference?

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-regression, statistical-learning

Can someone interpret me the line in the bold ? how it is different from p-value as p-value is also responsible for the same 5% error ? The text is from "An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R" by Trevor Hastie and Robert Tibshirani

> Given each individual p-values for each variable, why do we need to
>   look at the overall F-statistic?
>
> After all, it seems likely that if any one of the p-values for the
>   individual variables is very small, then at least one of the
>   predictors is related to the response. However, this logic is ﬂawed,
>   especially when the number of predictors p is large.
>
> For instance, consider an example in which p = 100 and H0 : β1 = β2 =
>   ...= βp = 0 is true, so no variable is truly associated with the
>   response. In this situation, about 5% of the p-values associated with
>   each variable (of the type shown in Table 3.4) will be below 0.05 by
>   chance. In other words, we expect to see approximately ﬁve small
>   p-values even in the absence of any true association between the
>   predictors and the response. In fact, we are almost guaranteed that we
>   will observe at least one p-value below 0.05 by chance!
>
> Hence, if we use the individual t-statistics and associated pvalues in
>   order to decide whether or not there is any association between the
>   variables and the response, there is a very high chance that we will
>   incorrectly conclude that there is a relationship.
>
> However, the F-statistic does not suﬀer from this problem because it
>   adjusts for the number of predictors. **Hence, if H0 is true, there is
>   only a 5% chance that the Fstatistic will result in a p-value below
>   0.05, regardless of the number of predictors or the number of observations**

Comment: If you're quoting a text, you need to give the details of the thing you're quoting (and properly mark the quoted parts as quotes).

Comment: @Geln_b new to this. Hope will take care of things next time,

Comment: It's important to take care of things _this time_....

Comment: @user110244 You can edit your question to include the title of the book and its authors.

Comment: @Peter thanks for suggestion. I have done what is asked.

Comment: The qouted text is misleading and incorrect.

Comment: The quoted texts compares t statistics to F statistics.  The issue with p values is the same in both.

Answer (score 4):

Reputed book? The example was somewhat conflated because it's trying to explain the shortcoming of multiple t-tests and yet using an F-test to describe type I error. It's slightly confusing.

Basically, suppose there are 5 groups and each group has a mean. We're interested to see if any of the groups has a mean that is different from others. There are generally two perceivable approaches:

**First approach**, use many t-tests to compare each mean against 0:
G1 vs. G2,
G1 vs. G3,
G1 vs. G4,
G1 vs. G5,
G2 vs. G3,
G2 vs. G4,
G2 vs. G5,
G3 vs. G4,
G3 vs. G5,
G4 vs. G5.

Totally there are 10 t-tests. Just as a kink of hypothesis testing, there is always a chance we will declare a difference even in reality there isn't one. This is called type I error. We often set this at 5% as a convention. Now, there are 10 tests, and each of them individually can have a 5% type I error rate. Chance is you will see some differences that are just due to randomness, and erroneously conclude there some means are different. In other words, using many t-test can inflate the chance of committing type I error, making it bigger than 5%.

The **second approach** is using an F-test, in this case an ANOVA. ANOVA tests collectively if any of the means is different from the rest. In a way, it groups all the t-tests together into this one big null hypothesis:

$H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2 = \mu_3 = \mu_4 = \mu_5$

Now, because it's still one single test, it does not face the problem like the ten t-tests have. And because of this, using an F-test instead of running many t-tests is a safer way to guard against mistakenly rejecting any null hypothesis (aka committing a type I error.)

---

Now, the implication can be broad. For instance, it's applicable to regression models. In regression model, it's crucial to examine the ANOVA results (aka the F-test result) of the model as a whole before diving into the p-values for each independent variables. If the overall F-test says none of the independent variable's slopes is different from 0, then even one of the independent variables has a p-value less than 0.05, we should not interpret it as if it's a significant independent variable.

Comment: +1 but can one really use an ANOVA to test the null that all means are equal to zero? Usually the null is that all means are equal *between each other* but not to some fixed value.

Comment: I have rejected an attempted edit in which it was implicitly assumed the ten t-tests in the first approach are independent--which they definitely are not.  This mistake, though, is of interest because it suggests a deeper analysis of your claims would be helpful in getting the point across.

Comment: @whuber Can't be 10 t-test give compound error (.95)^10 and leads to alpha = 1-(.95)^10= 0.40126. Am i right ?

Comment: @user110244 To be valid, your calculation requires independent results.  If those t-tests share data, such as a common control group, then they are not independent. This is the problem solved by the F test.

Answer (score 3):

If you have only one variable in the model, then t-test on a single variable and its p-value will be the same as F-test on an entire model and its p-value.

The difference is when you have more than one variable. In this case it is possible to have individual variable's p-values (from t-test) not significant, yet F-test p-values significant. This could point to potential multicollineraity issues, for instance, i.e. maybe you need to kick out a few variables from the model.

Comment: ok but performance wise both are having 5% error . correct ?

Comment: $\alpha=5$% is the significance level which you set before running the tests. It's up to you which $\alpha$ to set in both F- and t-test. It makes a sense to use the same $\alpha$, of course. If you set the same significance, and have only one variable in the model, then both tests will produce the same result.